# Plot dataframe then add vertical lines; how get custom legend text for all?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can plot a dataframe (2 "Y" values) and add vertical lines (2) to the plot, and I can specify custom legend text for either the Y values OR the vertical lines, but not both at the same time.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'y1' : [8., 6., 4., 2.], 'y2' : [-4., 13., 2.2, -1.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
ax = df.plot(x='x', y=['y1'], linestyle='-', color='b')
df.plot(x='x', y=['y2'], linestyle='--', color='y', ax=ax)
ax.legend(labels=['y1custom', 'y2custom'])
plt.axvline(x=1.5, color='r', linestyle='--', label='vline1.5custom')
plt.axvline(x=3.5, color='k', linestyle='--', label='vline3.5custom')
plt.legend()        # <---- comment out....or not....for different effects
plt.show()
```

A key line in the code is "plt.legend()".  With it in the code, I get this (note legend has dataframe column labels "y1" and "y2" instead of my desired custom labels):

[image: with plt.legend() call]

With "plt.legend()" removed, I get this (legend has my custom labels for the dataframe values only, legend for vertical lines does not even appear!):

[image: without plt.legend() call]

How can I get the best of both worlds, specifically the following (in whatever order) for my legend?:

```
y1custom
y2custom
vline1.5custom
vline3.5custom
```

Sure I could rename the columns of the dataframe first, but...ugh!  There must be a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to `legend()` overwrites the initially created legend. So you need to create one single legend with all the desired labels in.

This means you can get the current labels via `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` and replace those you do not like with something else. Then specify the new list of labels when calling `legend()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'y1' : [8., 6., 4., 2.], 'y2' : [-4., 13., 2.2, -1.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
ax = df.plot(x='x', y=['y1'], linestyle='-', color='b')
df.plot(x='x', y=['y2'], linestyle='--', color='y', ax=ax)

ax.axvline(x=1.5, color='r', linestyle='--', label='vline1.5custom')
ax.axvline(x=3.5, color='k', linestyle='--', label='vline3.5custom')

h,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels[:2] = ['y1custom','y2custom']
ax.legend(labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`label` can be passed to `plot()` as long as you specify the column being plotted:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'y1' : [8., 6., 4., 2.], 'y2' : [-4., 13., 2.2, -1.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

ax = df['y1'].plot(x='x', linestyle='-', color='b', label='y1custom')
df['y2'].plot(x='x', linestyle='--', color='y', ax=ax, label='y2custom')
plt.axvline(x=1.5, color='r', linestyle='--', label='vline1.5custom')
plt.axvline(x=3.5, color='k', linestyle='--', label='vline3.5custom')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This approach avoids having to mess around with the legend afterwards:

[image: matplotlib figure+custom legend]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
d = {'x' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'y1' : [8., 6., 4., 2.], 'y2' : [-4., 13., 2.2, -1.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
ax = df.plot(x='x', y=['y1'], linestyle='-', color='b')
df.plot(x='x', y=['y2'], linestyle='--', color='y', ax=ax)
l1 = plt.axvline(x=1.5, color='r', linestyle='--', label='vline1.5custom')
l2 = plt.axvline(x=3.5, color='k', linestyle='--', label='vline3.5custom')
#move ax.legend after axvlines and get_label
ax.legend(labels=['y1custom', 'y2custom',l1.get_label(),l2.get_label()])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a great and elegant answer. Thank you Scott